# Setting up an XML response for SOAP

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm having a real hard time with this issue.

Basically I've built a WebService using Java/JAX-WS, this is my Interface

```
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface OperationsInterface {

@WebResult(name = "result")
LoginResponse Login(@WebParam(name = "login") Login login);

@WebResult(name = "result")
String Purchase(@WebParam(name = "purchase") Purchase purchase);

}
```

Login is just a POJO that contains 2 strings (username and password)

LoginResponse is another POJO, it has this

```
String status;
int code;
String message;
SubscriptionTier subscriptionTier;
String accountNumber;
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

Nothing fancy, pretty simple in fact. The request is something like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ott="http://ott.amentum.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ott:Login>
         <login>
            <username>USERNAME</username>
            <password>1234</password>
         </login>
      </ott:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the response comes like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ott.amentum.net/">
         <result>
            <accountNumber>0110000076</accountNumber>
            <code>1</code>
            <firstName>JOHN</firstName>
            <lastName>DOE</lastName>
            <message>Login has been successful.</message>
            <status>success</status>
            <subscriptionTier>
               <tier>TVOD</tier>
               <tier>CANAL</tier>
               <tier>CATCHUP</tier>
            </subscriptionTier>
         </result>
      </ns2:LoginResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As far as I know, this is correct, however, my customer is expecting something like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ott.amentum.net/">
         <accountNumber>0410089676</accountNumber>
         <code>1</code>
         <firstName>MARIA DEL CARMEN</firstName>
         <lastName>PADILLA MARTIN</lastName>
         <message>Login has been successful.</message>
         <status>success</status>
         <subscriptionTier>
            <tier>TVOD</tier>
            <tier>CANAL</tier>
            <tier>CATCHUP</tier>
         </subscriptionTier>
      </ns2:LoginResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

They want me to remove the result tag, which is the name of the LoginResponse object I created to return the information.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why does it matter to the customer?  are they working with client code they can't change?

Comment: Apparently... It's something they already have in production, working with more than 1 system.